# How to extract row values from a cursor object?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I used this query `"SELECT English FROM Sheet1 WHERE Category_id='WL_1'"`. here it is returning 13 rows and 1 column but i am not getting how to extract those 13 rows values from cursor.
I am trying:

```
 for(i in 0 until testData!!.count){
     Log.e("HomeActivity", "Fetched column data:"+testData!!.getString(testData!!.getColumnIndex("English")))
   
      testData!!.moveToNext()
}
```

But it is running only 3 times and returning row 0 item only not row 1,2, and so on.
So please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
        String sql="SELECT English  FROM Sheet1 WHERE Category_id='"+WL_1+"' ";
        Cursor cr=db.query(sql);

        ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList();
        while (cr.moveToNext()) {
            try {
                String English = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("English"));

                arrayList.add(English);

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(activity," Something went wrong");
            }
        }
```